# I am facing exception while adding new place in google map in my android app

Tags: android, exception

I am currently working on my Final year Project which is on Android. I am using map API. I want to add a new place on my current location but I am facing this exception.

Error log[image]

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.example.hp.maps, PID: 10044
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: GoogleApiClient is not configured to use Places.GEO_DATA_API required for this call.
    at com.google.android.gms.common.internal.zzbo.zzb(Unknown Source)
    at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzbcp.zze(Unknown Source)
    at com.google.android.gms.location.places.internal.zzh.addPlace(Unknown Source)
    at com.example.hp.maps.AddNewPlace$1.onClick(AddNewPlace.java:116)
    at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4438)
    at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:18439)
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5095)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:786)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:602)
    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: add error text with question not image

Comment: I hope you can see now

Answer (score 0):

I guess you are using google api client object multiple times. If you are, then use two differents GoogleApiClient instances: one for GooglePlace API and another for which you are using(might be LocationService).

Answer (score 0):

Seems like mGoogleApiClient is not initialized or forget to indicate adding `Places.GEO_DATA_API`

```
mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient
                            .Builder(Context)
                            .addApi(Places.GEO_DATA_API)
```

Comment: mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
                // The next two lines tell the new client that “this” current class will handle connection stuff
                .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
                .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
                //fourth line adds the LocationServices API endpoint from GooglePlayServices
                .addApi(LocationServices.API)
                .build();

Comment: What about the `Places.GEO_DATA_API` ? The crash log says you : you attempt to use GeoDataApi but didn't indicate in `mGoogleApiClient`

Comment: I have already answered. Add this  `Places.GEO_DATA_API` to your GoogleApiClient instance.

Comment: i am still facing an exception

Comment: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                     Process: com.example.hp.maps, PID: 14439
                                                                     java.lang.IllegalStateException: GoogleApiClient is not connected yet.

Comment: I added the code sample above just to make sense! Do not use directly. Please connect to google api client first, then follow the onConnected method.

Comment: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                   Process: com.example.hp.maps, PID: 6718
                                                                   java.lang.RuntimeException: Failure delivering result ResultInfo{who=null, request=1, result=-1, data=Intent { act=inline-data (has extras) }} to activity {com.example.hp.maps/com.example.hp.maps.Profile}: java.lang.NullPointerException